# Kendo : The attr binding is not supported by the DropDownList widget

Tags: data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am trying to upgrade my kendo mobile application. When I tried to use the most recent kendo-core javascript library it is returning "The attr binding is not supported by the DropDownList widget" error.

My binding inside my html code is like

```
<script id="fieldsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li>
    <label data-bind="attr: { for: COLUMN_NAME}, text: COLUMN_TITLE"></label><span class="targettrash"></span>
    # if (get("FORM_FIELD_TYPE") == "I") {#
    <input data-bind="value: VALUE, disabled: DISABLED, attr: { type: DATA_TYPE, name: COLUMN_NAME, id: COLUMN_NAME} ,style: {textTransform:ENTRY_FORMAT}" />
    #}else if (get("FORM_FIELD_TYPE") == "T"){#
    <textarea data-bind="value: VALUE, disabled: DISABLED, attr: { type: DATA_TYPE, name: COLUMN_NAME, id: COLUMN_NAME} ,style: {textTransform:ENTRY_FORMAT}" />
    #}else if (get("FORM_FIELD_TYPE") == "L"){#
    <input data-bind="value: VALUE, disabled: DISABLED, attr: { type: DATA_TYPE, name: COLUMN_NAME, id: COLUMN_NAME}" />
    #}else{#
    <select data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="value: VALUE, disabled: DISABLED, source: options, attr: { id: COLUMN_NAME" data-text-field="OPTION_DESC" data-value-field="OPTION_ID" />
    #}#

    </li>
</script>
```

The javascript part is

```
                    $('#' + obsRecordFields.fields[i].COLUMN_NAME).kendoDropDownList({
                        dataSource : dataSource,
                        dataTextField : "OPTION_DESC ",
                        dataValueField : "OPTION_ID"
                    });
```

which functionality is changed and how should a correct my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute binding is not supported in DropDownList anymore (it was supported before).

I needed to define the attributes in my dynamically created forms. What I did was defining the attributes after to form was created.

The following code worked fine inside the form creation loop

```
                var j = i + 1;
                var $elem = $("form#recordDetailForm ul > li:nth-child(" + j + ") select[data-role='dropdownlist']");
                if ($elem.length==1) {
                    $elem.attr('id',obsRecordFields.fields[i].COLUMN_NAME);
                    $elem.attr('type',obsRecordFields.fields[i].DATA_TYPE);
                    $elem.attr('name',obsRecordFields.fields[i].COLUMN_NAME);
```